How to force Blender to utilize the XDG File Picker portal (instead of its custom picker)?
The XDG File Picker portal is the Freedesktop-standard (hence the retrograde XDG moniker) cross-desktop-environment file picker implementation. I'm asking because I would be surprised if it were not yet implemented.

As far as I know, Blender doesn't support any file browsers other than its own, because addons, extensions, preferences and importers integrate into its UI through Python scripts

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos, that's a good reason for them not to, although I'd be surprised if the portal didn't support extensions (like AOSP's com.android.documentsui) although that's outside the purview of this forum. I'll assume that they don't support it, regardless.
